# Android Material Date Picker is slow

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialog, material-components-android

Both of [these](https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android#using-date-pickers) `Date Pickers` take at least 1 second to load, when I follow the example code. That is:

```
  val datePicker =
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().setTitleText("Start date")
            .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()).build()
  datePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "Start")
```

I was surprised to see the Google Analytics app using the same components, but with way less latency. The Google Analytics app uses a normal `Material Date Picker` in the Custom tab, under Dashboard. The loading time for the `Picker` is reduced to a few milliseconds there. I wonder how I can improve my code, to achieve such speeds?

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 3):

changing the StartYear and EndYear for the Date Picker control made a big difference to the performance of the control in the PowerApp we were creating. The defaults appeared to be 1899 (StartYear) and 9999 (EndYear) - this was for a date field in a SharePoint custom list.

please set minimum start year and maxmimum select year

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The default's seemed to be 1900-2100 for the Material Date Picker. Adding constraints did improve the speed a bit, but it is nowhere near as fast as the Google Analytics app. I wonder if it they preload the dialog somehow